# Is it possible to connect a local flutter app to an online nodeJS backend?

Tags: node.js, flutter, vps

I was looking to create a mobile application using Flutter for my frontend and NodeJS for my backend. After doing some research I saw that it was possible to integrate the two through the backend NodeJS server and have both sides listen to a specific host and port so data can be communicated between them. However, all the tutorials I've seen use a localhost as an example. Would it be possible to create a flutter application on my local machine and have the backend NodeJS server hosted on a VPS so the application would be able to connect to the VPS and communicate with the backend server there?

Comment: Just change the `localhost` url to your server ip/domain?

Comment: I understand that i can do that but I mean is it possible or will it cause issues such as authentication, and if so How would i carry it out?

Comment: Yes Its possible. If your server is configured correctly it should working same as localhost.